# Выделение памяти для аллокатора

Tags: алгоритм, память

пишу свой аллокатор на C++, по задумке, аллокатор должен быть в состоянии выделять куски памяти произвольного размера(размер может быть ограничен сверху, но в заданном пределе может быть любым). Для организации аллокатора я решил использовал неявный список блоков, т.е. перед каждым блоком размещается несколько байтов служебной информации, которая показывает размер блока и свободен ли он. При подобной организации неясно, какой объем информации нужно выделять с помощью malloc при создании аллокатора, т.к. неясно, какой объем служебной информации нам потребуется. Вопрос следующий: есть ли общепринятые подходы для решения этой проблемы?

Comment: А  объем неслужебной информации, которая может быть выделелена задан? Вообще, тут объем служебной информации напрямую зависит от количества запросов (выделенных блоков). Чем больше запросов с малым объемом данных, тем больше будет служебной информации.

Comment: Да, объем неслужебной информации известен. Понятно, что чем больше выделенных блоков, тем больше служебной информации. В этом и вопрос: сколько дополнительного места нужно выделять.

Comment: Если выделять всегда выровненную, скажем для double память, то минимальный блок будет 16 байт (8 служебная + 8 данные). Вообще говоря, это глупо. Тут надо выделять (м.б. динамически) подпулы такой памяти и организовывать в них список свободных + нужно хранить границы таких подпулов, чтобы free могла определить, что именно ей возвращают (алгоритм аллокации и возврата будет разный для таких подпулов и остальных (больших) блоков). У вас, вообще, какая предполагаемая модель использования?

Comment: Это чисто учебная задача, поэтому модели использования у меня нет. Но я хотел сделать аллокатор в предположении, что он должен хорошо работать при частых обращениях на выделение/освобождение небольших кусков памяти.

Comment: Ну, я бы сделал 2 пула, растущих навстречу. Один для 8-ми байтных кусков, без служебной информации. При возврате ничего не объединяется, возвращаемый блок попадает в список свободных. Аллокация маленького блока происходит в первую очередь прямо из этого списка. Понятно, что это очень быстро. Для понимания, что возвращают 8-ми байтный блок при таком подходе достаточно 2 сравнения адресов. Во второй части я бы реализовал традиционный метод с 8-ми байтами служебной информации перед выделенной памятью. При возврате такого блока он сливается со смежными свободными. Это потребует просмотра списка.

Comment: При таком выборе у вас появится устойчивая позиция в дискуссиях с преподователем и разные направления для исследований быстродействия, вероятностей невозможности удовлетворения очередного запроса из-за фрагментации и т.п. В общем, развлекуха обеспечена.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.